# Batchfile to delete all folders but the latest AND a special folder

Tags: batch-file, directory, delete-file, special-folders

hope you can help me. I am looking for a way to use batchscript to delete all folders in a subfolder *except*

- the very newest folder AND
- a special folder named "BACKUP".

So the backup folder can be older, but it needs to be kept.
All other folders except the one with the newest date should be deleted.

There will be files in all of those folders, but there are no hidden files or subfolders, so this needs not to be considered in this case.

I found a lot of solutions here to either spare the backup folder or delete everything except the newest, but I cannot seem to find a solution that can do both.

`for /d %%i in ("C:\Parent\*") do if /i not "%%~nxi"=="BACKUP" del /s /q "%%i"`

I.e. like this, but it will not keep the newest folder.
All the other folders except the backup folder have names like "20220215" "20210405".

Thank you for any help you can give.

KR
Susanne

Answer (score 1):

Build a list of directories by [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) sorted by age from newest to oldest, filter out unwanted ones by [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), then use [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to iterate through the list but skip the very first item:

```
rem // Change into root directory:
pushd "C:\Parent" && (
    rem /* Loop through matching directories sorted by last modification date (due to `/T:W`)
    rem    in descending order and skip the very first (that is the lastly modified) item: */
    for /F "skip=1 delims= eol=|" %%I in ('
        dir /B /A:D-H-S /O:-D /T:W "????????" ^| findstr /V /I /X "BACKUP"
    ') do rd /S /Q "%%I"
    rem // Return from root directory:
    popd
)
```

Since [`del`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html) only deletes files, [`rd`](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) is used instead to delete (sub-)directories too rather than leaving behind empty (sub-)directory trees.

The line `dir /B /A:D-H-S /O:-D /T:W "????????" ^| findstr /V /I /X "BACKUP"` could be replaced by the following in order to do stricter filtering:

```
        dir /B /A:D-H-S /O:-D /T:W "????????" ^| findstr /I /X "[12][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][01][0123456789][0123][0123456789]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set "skipme=Y"
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /ad /od "c:\parent\*"') do if /i "%%b" neq "backup" if defined skipme (set "skipme=") else (ECHO rd /s /q "c:\parent\%%b")
```

Should remove all the required directories. Well, report the directorynames that would be delete if the `echo` keyword was deleted.

`skipme` is initialised to a value. for each directory found, with the exception of `backup`, check whether `skipme` has a value; set `skipme` to *empty* if it's set (which will only be for the first directory found that isn't `backup` from a date-ordered `dir` list), otherwise remove the directory.

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried the other suggested solution first as it was a little easier to understand / read for me, and as it already worked out as intended, I did not try yours. Nevertheless, thank you for your time and effort, I will keep this bookmarked for tryout.